# "Combine" TF-IDF scores for single class of documents within corpus

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tf-idf, text-classification

Let's say I've calculated the TF-IDF scores for a corpus of documents, resulting in a matrix of TF-IDF features. If a subset of those documents are of a certain class, can I somehow "combine" the scores of that subset to get a single value for each feature in that class in a meaningful way?

For example, if I have a corpus of 1000 documents, and `corpus[0:200]` are of class A, then can I take rows 0-200 of the tf-idf scores and somehow combine them so that I can say, "In class A, features[3] has a score of 0.5."

My hope is to extract the most meaningful terms from each class within the corpus. Is there a reasonable way to do this? Does my question demonstrate a misunderstanding of the concept to begin with? Any feedback at all is wildly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you described is like "feature selection". After you extracted the tf-idf score, your document may look like this:

```
doc1: london:0.2 british:0.5 travel:0.1
doc2: coffee:0.2 brazil:0.1 travel:0.5
doc3: meat:0.8 avian 0.001 birds:0.2
doc4: agriculture:0.5 meat:0.5 chicken:0.01
```

Suppose doc1 and doc2 are class 0:"cities" and doc3 and doc4 are class 1: "poultry". You can then calcuate the expected `mutual information` of a term `t` and a class `c`.

See details for how to perform mutual-information based feature selection at [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/mutual-information-1.html).